# Request for multiple similar models by one query

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

How Symfony can realize query that response multiple models?

Imagine that we have 3 models: `Adv`, `AdvT1 extends Adv` and `AdvT2 extends Adv`

So the goal is to retrieve all models AdvT1 and AdvT2 from query result where corresponding model type is set in the column of table `adv`.

`SELECT * FROM ONLY adv NATURAL FULL JOIN adv_t1 NATURAL FULL JOIN adv_t2 order by id;`

Tables schema are:

```
CREATE TABLE public.adv (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title text,
    price integer
);

CREATE TABLE public.adv_t1 (
    size integer
) INHERITS (public.adv);

CREATE TABLE public.adv_t2 (
    color integer
) INHERITS (public.adv);
```

Here is analyzing of queries explanation where compare left join with natural join.

```
"SELECT * FROM ONLY adv NATURAL FULL JOIN adv_t1 NATURAL FULL JOIN adv_t2 order by id";
```

Cost - 245.87; Duration - 0.132

```
"SELECT * FROM adv LEFT JOIN adv_t1 ON adv_t1.id = adv.id LEFT JOIN adv_t2 ON adv_t2.id = adv.id order by adv.id";
```

Cost - 1538.94; Duration - 0.059

Comment: Please have a look to : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks Mathieu for reply, I have read a doctrine article that you admit. So here is collusion: Or to make one super table and host empty cells or  use join-able tables with foreign key. Am I correct?

Comment: Making `UNION` will be more expensive than using a table with empty colomn, in my opinion.

Comment: Unfortunately ```UNION``` return columns those are in first table so it can not be decision to make a query as  I know.

Comment: Use `@InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")` as doctrine annotation it will create a `discr` column to each object.

Comment: Okay. And one more question: if in child entities would be same fields for example ```city``` would it use one table column or it should have two separated?

Comment: The same column.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathieu!